# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server ver. for the right syntax to use near "" at line 1

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, authentication

I made a login page, using C# and HelioHost MySQL. Wrote everything that was neccesary for the connection, still there is an error. Tried to fix it myself but I decided to reach in here.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace TestLoginForm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int i;
        MySqlConnection consql = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=tommy.heliohost.org;port=3306;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;uid=user;password='secretpass'");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            i = 0;
            consql.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = consql.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from users where username ='"+usernameBox.Text+"'and password'"+passwordBox.Text+"'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            i = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
            consql.Close();

            if (i == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You have entered invalid credentials", "Invalid credentials", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                usernameBox.Text = "";
                passwordBox.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection with database was successfully established and all input data matches the table contents", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If anybody could help and fix whatever error there is in this code I would be really thankful.

Comment: The error is due to the connection  string :"Data Source=tommy.heliohost.org;port=3306;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;uid=user;password='secretpass'"  The server may not be running, you are using the wrong port, the server is rejecting the request.  It is hard to say exactly what is wrong.  I usually recommend trying from another application that uses mysql to determine if the connection string is correct.

Comment: TLDR; Use placeholders. 1) Mitigate SQL injection (including *accidentally* broken queries), and 2) simpler query text avoids *trivially avoidable* mistakes like this..

Comment: Written with placeholders (aka a parameterized query) the error is clear: “select * from users where username =@usernameand password@password” — now the syntax issue(s) should be self-evident, as I directly transposed placeholder names.

Comment: Also, that is an *insecure* way to deal with passwords as they are *plain text*.. however, there are many GOOD tutorials out there on how to write an authentication provider (or better, use something already written), so it might be good to find one and scrap whatever recommended code or an approach like the above..

Answer (score 2):

There are equal signs missing from your query, and it is quite obvious that you will do this kind of mistake as you are breaking down your string into several parts which will cause unreadability.

**Here is a much clean and safer way to do it**

```
MySqlCommand cmd = consql.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @uname AND password =@pass ";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname",usernameBox.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass",passwordBox.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So in this way you write your query in a single string and define a @key wherever you want to insert a value. and provide the value of this key like this:

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key",value)
```

Answer (score 1):

> "select * from users where username ='"+usernameBox.Text+"'and password'"+passwordBox.Text+"'";
> If you insert a name+password, you get:

```
select * from users where username='user' and password'password'
```

You have to add an equal sign.

```
select * from users where username='user' and password='password'
```

Furthermore *you are vulnerable to SQL-Injections* since a parametrized query is not used.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the problem and pointing out that I am vurnerable for SQL-Injections. I will look into more safe ways to make a C# login form that is invurnerable to actions like these.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an equal sign after `'password'` in your query statement. Take a look at this.

```
 "select * from users where username ='"+usernameBox.Text+"'and password ='"+passwordBox.Text+"'"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't notice such small yet important error. Everything works now :)

Comment: ⚠️ This approach is insecure as it allows SQL Injection, buggy as it can result in ‘accidental errors’, and does not follow good practices. Use a parameterized query.